# Why there is no .dll file after building the source?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm gonna build a dll form below source code:

HelloDLL.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLLDIR_EX
#define DLLDIR_EX __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLDIR_EX __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

class DLLDIR_EX HelloDLL
{
public:
    HelloDLL();
    ~HelloDLL();

    void hello();
    static void helloStatic();
};
```

And the implementation is just like this:

HelloDLL.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloDLL.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


HelloDLL::HelloDLL()
{
}

void HelloDLL::hello()
{
    cout << "Hello world of DLL" << endl;
}

void HelloDLL::helloStatic()
{
    cout << "Hello static world of DLL" << endl;
}

HelloDLL::~HelloDLL()
{
}
```

After building the project (Ctrl + Shift + B), There is a couple of usual generated files into the Debug folder of the project with below types:

- Application
- Export Library File
- Incremental Library File
- Object File Library
- Program Debug Database

But there is no .dll file...
Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this case?

Comment: You probably did not build a dll project. Check your project type.

Comment: @nvoigt: Actually, I have no robust idea how to check the project type... However, I just started my job with a common win32 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your **Project Properties**, go to **Configuration Properties**, **General** and look for the entry **Configuration Type**. Make sure it's set to the proper output type. By default it will be set to **Application (.exe)**. What you're looking for is **Dynamic Library (.dll)**.

[image: Screenshot from MSVC 2013]

Comment: Thank you!... The type was .exe and after I changed it to dll, the desired .dll file would been generated!